# Contact Form 7 - add custom function on email send

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

Just playing around with `Wordpress / Contact Form 7`.
Is it possible / do you know how to **add custom javascript function on successful email send event**?

Comment: There are a couple of filters inside the function `mail_callback()`, located in `/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/classes.php` that may be handy, but donnow how... This [forum search](http://wordpress.org/search/contact-form-7+send+javascript?forums=1) may be useful as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply add you JavaScript function to your page then find the **Additional Settings** field at the bottom of the contact form management page and use the `on_sent_ok` JavaScript action hook like so:

```
on_sent_ok: "MY_JavaScript_function_Name();"
```

Comment: Info: As of version *7.5* this is deprecated, use [DOM events](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/)